# Two integrals whose answer involves gamma function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

For $h>0$, define two integrals as

$$I_0 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz \frac{\sinh^2z}{(\cosh z)^{4h+2}},$$
and
$$I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz \: z\left( \frac{\sinh z}{(\cosh z)^{4h+3}} - 2h  \frac{\sinh^3 z}{(\cosh z)^{4h+3}}\right).$$

Then, I numerically checked that
$$I_0 = \frac{\sqrt\pi \Gamma(2h)}{2\Gamma\left(2h + \frac32\right)}$$
and
$$I_1 = -\frac12 I_0.$$

How can I derive this result?

Comment: Making the substitution $\sinh z=x$
$$I=2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{2h+1}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt t}{(1+t)^{2h+3/2}}dt$$
Next, $x=\frac{1}{1+t}$
$$I=\int_0^1(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}x^{2h-1}dx=B\big(\frac{3}{2};2h\big)=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)\Gamma(2h)}{\Gamma(2h+3/2)}$$
IBP
$$d\bigg(\frac{\sinh^2z}{\cosh^{4h+2}z}\bigg)=\frac{2\sinh z\cosh^2 z-(4h+2)\sin^3z}{\cosh^{4h+3}z}dz=2\frac{\sinh z-2h\sinh^3z}{\cosh^{4h+3}z}dz$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with the antiderivative$$ \int  \frac{\sinh ^2(z)}{\cosh ^{4 h+2}(z)}\,dz=\frac{\sqrt{-\sinh ^2(z)}\, \text{csch}(z) }{(4
   h+1)\cosh ^{4 h+1}(z)}\, \,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},-2 h-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}-2 h;\cosh ^2(z)\right)$$

If $z>0$, it reduces to  $$-\frac{1}{2} i B_{\cosh ^2(z)}\left(-2 h-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
If $z<0$, it reduces to  $$\frac{1}{2} i B_{\cosh ^2(z)}\left(-2 h-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
If $z=0$, it is just
$$\frac{i \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-2 h\right)}{2 (4 h+1) \Gamma (1-2 h)}$$

For sure, use the symmetry and
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \frac{\sinh ^2(z)}{\cosh ^{4 h+2}(z)}\,dz=\frac{\, _2F_1(1,-2 h-1;2 h+1;-1)-1}{2 h (2 h+1)}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\Gamma (2 h)}{2\, \Gamma \left(2 h+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$