# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(\cosh x)^\alpha} dx$ for $\alpha>0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

I want to evaluate the integral
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(\cosh x)^\alpha} dx,$$
where $\alpha>0$ is a constant. The Mathematica says that the answer is
$$\frac{2^{\alpha +2} \, _4F_3\left(\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{\alpha
   }{2},\frac{\alpha }{2},\alpha ;\frac{\alpha }{2}+1,\frac{\alpha
   }{2}+1,\frac{\alpha }{2}+1;-1\right)}{\alpha ^3}.$$

However, what I want is a simpler final answer than the above form involving hypergeometric function. I expect that a simplification is possible, since analogous simplification was possible for a similar integral. (See my previous question [Integral where Mathematica gives hypergeometric function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524063/integral-where-mathematica-gives-hypergeometric-function))

Comment: If you can figure out what the coefficients are for $ \left ( \frac{x}{1+x^2} \right)^{\alpha}$ in relation to $x$ and call it $g(n,\alpha)$, then the answer is $$ 2^{2+\alpha} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{g(n,\alpha)}{n^3}$$

Comment: A binomial expansion of $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^{-\alpha}$ might work. Thanks @ParclyTaxel

Comment: By taking the binomial expansion of $(1+e^{2x})^{-\alpha}$, you can reduce the integral to $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{2^\alpha (\alpha)_k}{k!(\alpha+2k)^3}$$, where $(\alpha)_k$ is the falling factorial, but I don't see a way to simplify things further without assuming $\alpha$ is an integer.

Comment: Thanks all for comments!

Comment: Not sure how much this helps but
[Sech can be written in terms of ${}_4F_3$](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sech/26/01/):
$$\operatorname{sech} z=\frac{4\pi}{\pi^2+4z^2}{}_4F_3\left(\begin{matrix}(1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}-\frac{-iz}{\pi},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{iz}{\pi}) \\ (\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{iz}{\pi},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{iz}{\pi})\end{matrix}\bigg|~-1\right)$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using only Mathematica:

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{x^2}{\cosh ^{\alpha }(x)} \, dx=\\\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } 2^{\alpha } \left(e^{-x}+e^x\right)^{-\alpha } x^2 \,
   dx=\\\mathcal{L}_s\left[\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \mathcal{L}_A^{-1}\left[2^{\alpha } \left(e^{-x}+A e^x\right)^{-\alpha } x^2\right](s) \,
   dx\right](1)=\\\mathcal{L}_s\left[\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{2^{\alpha } e^{-e^{-2 x} s-x \alpha } s^{-1+\alpha } x^2}{\Gamma (\alpha )} \,
   dx\right](1)=\mathcal{L}_s\left[\frac{2^{-3+\alpha } s^{-1+\frac{\alpha }{2}} \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \log ^2(s)}{\Gamma (\alpha )}-\frac{2^{-2+\alpha }
   s^{-1+\frac{\alpha }{2}} \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \log (s) \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}{\Gamma (\alpha )}+\frac{2^{-3+\alpha }
   s^{-1+\frac{\alpha }{2}} \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma (\alpha )}+\frac{2^{-3+\alpha } s^{-1+\frac{\alpha
   }{2}} \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}{\Gamma (\alpha )}\right](1)=\\\frac{2^{-2+\alpha } \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha
   }{2}\right)^2 \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}{\Gamma (\alpha )}$$
$$=\frac{\operatorname B\left(\frac\alpha2,\frac12\right)\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac\alpha2\right)}2$$

where: $\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)$ is PolyGamma function,

$\mathcal{L}_A^{-1}[f(A)](s)$ is InverseLaplaceTransform,

$\mathcal{L}_A[f(A)](s)$ is LaplaceTransform.

MMA code:

`LaplaceTransform[ Integrate[ InverseLaplaceTransform[2^\[Alpha] (E^-x + A*E^x)^-\[Alpha] x^2,  A, s] // PowerExpand, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},  Assumptions -> {\[Alpha] > 0, s > 0}], s, A] /.  A -> 1 // FullSimplify`

Comment: Wow..! Thanks for your amazing manipulation!

Comment: This is nice and moreover elegant !

Answer (score 4):

Just to add the nice solution by @Mariusz Iwaniuk - we can find a general formula for $x^n (\,n=0,1,2...)$ in the integrand.

Let's denote
$\displaystyle J(\beta)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{\beta x}}{\cosh ^\alpha x}dx, \,\text{then} \,\,I(n)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\cosh ^\alpha x}dx=\frac{\partial^n}{\partial\beta^n}J(\beta)\bigg|_{\beta=0}$

and
$$J(\beta)=2^\alpha\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{(\alpha+\beta) x}}{(e^{2x}+1) ^\alpha }dx\overset{t=e^x}=2^\alpha\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{\alpha+\beta-1}}{(t^2+1) ^\alpha }dt=2^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-1}}{(x+1) ^\alpha }dx$$
$$\overset{t=\frac{1}{x+1}}{=}\,2^{\alpha-1}\int_0^1(1-t)^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-1}t^{\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}-1}dt=2^{\alpha-1} B\Big(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2};\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\Big)=\frac{2^{\alpha-1}\Gamma\big(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\big)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$

$$\boxed{\,I(n)=\frac{2^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial\beta^n}e^{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\big)+\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\big)}\bigg|_{\beta=0}=\frac{2^{\alpha-1-n}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial s^n}e^{\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}+s\big)+\ln\Gamma\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}-s\big)}\bigg|_{s=0}\,}$$
For the particular cases $n=0,\,1,\,2,...$
$$I(0)=\frac{2^{\alpha-1}\Gamma^2\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$
$$I(1)=\frac{2^{\alpha-2}\Gamma\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}+s\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}-s\big)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\Big(\psi\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}+s\big)-\psi\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}-s\big)\Big)\bigg|_{s=0}=0$$
$$I(2)=\frac{2^{\alpha-3}\Gamma^2\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\bigg[\Big(\psi\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)-\psi\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)\Big)^2+\Big(\psi^{(1)}\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)+\psi^{(1)}\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)\Big)\bigg]=\frac{2^{\alpha-2}\Gamma^2\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\psi^{(1)}\Big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\Big)$$
etc.

Comment: Thanks for the computation of the "generating function"! Computation of the generating function is rather easier.